# `hhline` adding a strange vertical line distortion

Tags: tables, longtable, rules

I am using horizontal and vertical lines in a `longtable` environment to create a kind of tree-like internal structure. Since I need to color some cells with the `colortbl` package, I can't use `\cline`, so I've tried to use the `hhline` package instead. This mostly works; however, there is a strange distortion in some of the vertical lines:

[image: problem]

I do not fully understand what is going on here - where is this distorted pixel (?) coming from, and how do I put it back into its place?

(Also, if there is a more elegant way to draw a tree-table like this, I would be happy to learn about it…)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{|l}{#2}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{|lllll|}
    \hline
    \mc{3}{one}                                & foo & bar \\
                & \mc{2}{two}                  & foo & bar \\ 
                & \mc{1}{}     & \mc{1}{three} & foo & bar \\ 
                & \mc{1}{}     & \mc{1}{four}  & foo & bar \\ 
    \hhline{|~|~---}    
                & \mc{1}{}     &               &     &     \\
                & \mc{2}{five}                 & foo & bar \\ 
                & \mc{1}{}     & \mc{1}{six}   & foo & bar \\ 
                & \mc{1}{}     & \mc{1}{seven} & foo & bar \\ 
    \hhline{|~|~---}    
                & \mc{1}{}     &               &     &     \\
    \hhline{|~----}    
                &              &               &     &     \\
    \hline
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The basic problem is that this is wrong:

```
\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{|l}{#2}}
```

except in the first column LaTeX table rules are always the *right* edge of the preceding cell. Sometimes you can get away with it, but here you see the rule at the right edge of one cell not lining up with one at the left edge of a cell in the next row. So you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{l|}{#2}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{|lllll|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|l}{one}         & foo & bar \\
     \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}     & \multicolumn{2}{l}{two}   & foo & bar \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}  & \mc{1}{}     & three & foo & bar \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}  & \mc{1}{}     & four  & foo & bar \\ 
    \hhline{|~|~---}    
     \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}   &      &               &     &     \\
          \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{five}& foo & bar \\ 
     \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}   & \mc{1}{}     & six  & foo & bar \\ 
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}   & \mc{1}{}     & seven & foo & bar \\ 
    \hhline{|~|~---}    
     \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}  &     &               &     &     \\
    \hhline{|~----}    
                &              &               &     &     \\
    \hline
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting... in my case exactly the opposite was the remedy: moving the bars in front. This was necessary to get vertical lines like the ones above be drawn without gaps to horizontal `hhlines` when using the `cellcolor` comand. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (which uses PGF/TikZ to draw the rules).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lllll}
\Block[draw]{*-*}{}
\Block{1-2}{one} & & & foo & bar \\
& \Block[borders={left,bottom}]{8-*}{} \Block[l]{1-2}{\; two} & & foo & bar \\
& & \Block[borders={left,bottom}]{2-*}{} three & foo & bar \\
& & four & foo & bar \\
\\
& \Block[l]{1-2}{\; five} & & foo & bar \\
& & \Block[borders={left,bottom}]{2-*}{} six & foo & bar \\
& & seven & foo & bar \\
\\
\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]